# Is there a google api to verify if a gmail is valid from java?

Tags: java, google-api, gmail, email-validation, email-verification

I have to debug a google contact management app and the problem is sometimes there is some synchronization problem because some mail are deleted on google servers but they appear active in application.

Is there a google api to check if a mail is still active ?
If not, what do you think would be the best way to  validate a gmail from a java application ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/getProfile

Passing "userId" parameter don't forget about @gmail.com

In case of non-existing account you won't get Http status 200

Answer (score 0):

Try this
https://bounceinspector.com/api.php#java

in the link below change:
1- EMAIL_ADRESS_TO_VERIFY by the email to verify
2- Your_Domain_Name by your domain name or 127.0.0.1

```
https://bounceinspector.com/api1/api.php?email=EMAIL_ADRESS_TO_VERIFY&domain=Your_Domain_Name
```

in the commande below change Your_API_KEY_HERE by the key corresponding to your domain included in the url params (you will find it in the domains page)

```
httpConn.setRequestProperty("api_key", "Your_API_KEY_HERE");
```

You will get a response like this:

```
{
"error_status":0,
"score":99,
"result":1,
"email":"example@email.com"
}
```